# Show by substitution $z=xe^y$ that $x \dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^{-(x+y)} - 1 -x$ reduces to $\dfrac{dz}{dx} + z = e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to work this out but can't seem to find the way to do it.

Show by the substitution of $z=xe^y$ that

$x \dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^{-(x+y)} - 1 -x$

reduces to

$\dfrac{dz}{dx} + z = e^{-x}$

And once this has been shown, find the particular solution to the **original** differential equation for $y(1) = -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of your comments, let me try address the question by properly interpreting the problem.

You're given the differential equation $xu'(x)=e^{-x-u(x)}-1-x$.

Let $y$ be a differentiable function.

Now consider a new function $z$, given by $z(x)=xe^{y(x)}$.

The problem now asks you to prove that for all $x$ in a certain interval $I$ which contains $1$ (because of the initial condition), the following holds: $$xy'(x)=e^{-x-y(x)}-1-x\iff z'(x)+z(x)=e^{-x}\tag{EQ}$$

Due to divisions by $x$ that will be performed, it's better to assume from the start that $0\not \in I$.

Given $x\in I$, some useful facts are:

- $z(x)\neq 0$;
- $z'(x)=e^{y(x)}+xy'(x)e^{y(x)}=(1+xy'(x))e^{y(x)}$, which is equivalent to
- $z'(x)e^{-y(x)}-1=xy'(x)$;
- Since $z(x)=xe^{y(x)}\iff e^{-y(x)}=\dfrac x{z(x)}$, the line above is equivalent to
- $xy'(x)=z'(x)\dfrac{x}{z(x)}-1$

Now I'll prove the equivalence $(\text{EQ})$.

$\boxed{\implies}$

Suppose $xy'(x)=e^{-x-y(x)}-1-x$. The fifth bullet above justifies the first equality below, while the third bullet justifies the last equality:
$$z'(x)\dfrac x{z(x)}-1=e^{-x-y(x)}-1-x=e^{-x}e^{-y(x)}-1-x=e^{-x}\dfrac x{z(x)}-1-x.$$

So $$z'(x)\dfrac x{z(x)}=e^{-x}\dfrac x{z(x)}-x.$$ 
Thus  $z'(x)+z(x)=e^{-x}$, as required.

$\boxed{\Longleftarrow}$ Since all of the above are actually equivalences, this follows immediately. You should verify this. Note further that this direction is the one that actually matters because it tells you that if $z$ is a solution of $u'+u=\dfrac 1\exp$, then $y$ given by $y(x)=\log \left(\dfrac{z(x)}x\right)$ is a solution to the original differential equation.

I'll leave actually solving the differential equation to you.

Comment: The only part that is still confusing me is how you differentiate z?

Comment: @Finance Given my clarification of the interpretation of the problem, you shouldn't be having any trouble with it. You have $z(x)=xe^{y(x)}$. I differentiated $z$ using the product rule and the chain rule. Does this help?

Comment: Using the product rule I get - $e^y + xe^y$

Comment: @Finance You forgot the chain rule. What is the derivative of $x\mapsto to e^{y(x)}$?

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused, I know the chain rule but I'm finding it hard to see it applied here, could you explain further?

Comment: @Finance I had a typo in my previous comment, it was meant to be $x\mapsto e^{y(x)}$. Let's see. Set $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=e^{y(x)}$. Note that $z(x)=f(x)g(x)$. The product rule tells you that $z'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$, so let's find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$. Well, $f'(x)=1$. To find $g'(x)$ note that $g(x)=(\exp\circ y)(x)$. The chain rule then yields $g'(x)=\exp'(y(x))y'(x)=e^{y(x)}y'(x)$, gluing everything back together yields $z'(x)=e^{y(x)}+xe^{y(x)}y'(x)$.

Comment: @Finance Do you require further help with this?

Comment: It's still a little confusing but I'm not sure how better you could explain, I just can't see why there is a dy/dx there in this particular case, I know e^y is dependent on x but why does that yield a dy/dx. If you can think of a better way to explain it, please do, otherwise it's not that big a deal. I do however need help with this question urgently - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771559/expressing-function-in-terms-of-unit-step-function

Comment: @Finance Sorry. I can't help you with that question. I don't know what it's about. as for this one, the best I can do is illustrate with an example. We want to differentiate $g(x)=e^{y(x)}$. Let's see how it works with a specific $y$, say, $y(x)=x^2$. Then We want to differentiate $g(x)=e^{x^2}$ and the chain rule gives $g'(x)=\underbrace{2x}_{y'(x)}\,\cdot \,\underbrace{e^{x^2}}_{e^{y(x)}}$.

Comment: I tried to join chat but am not registered and couldn't find a way to sign up with this account.

Comment: @Finance if you want to sign up, click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmath.stackexchange.com%2f). If you wish me join the chat, make sure you ping me first.

Answer (score 0):

$$z=xe^y\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=e^y+xe^y\frac{dy}{dx}=e^y(1+x\frac{dy}{dx})$$

$$\implies x\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-y}\frac{dz}{dx}-1=\frac xz\frac{dz}{dx}-1\  \ \ \ (1)$$

and $$e^{-(x+y)}-1-x=e^{-x}\cdot\frac xz-1-x\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Equate  $(1),(2)$  and multiply either sides by $z$

Comment: Doesnt $dz/dx = e^y$ since we are differentiating wrt $x$ and $e^y$ is treated as a constant?

Comment: I still don't know why $dz/dx = e^y + xe^ydy/dx$ Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Finance, $y$ is a dependent variable of $x$