# Expressing function in terms of unit step function

Tags: laplace-transform

I have trouble expressing functions in terms of the unit step function, if someone could explain how it works that would be great.

For example -

$g(t) = t^2$ when $0 \le t < 2$

$4$ when  $t\ge2$

It could do with some formatting help but I hope you can read understand the question, please ask and I will clarify if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(t)=t^2*(H(t)-H(t-2))+4H(t-2)$$

$H(t)$ is the step function (Heaviside).
It's not difficult at all, you have just to "draw" the interval with the step function.

- If you multiply a function for $H(t)-H(t-2)$ this means that you
  "cut" the function in the interval between $0$ and $2$.
- If you multiply the function for just $H(t-2)$ means that the
  function starts at $t=2$ and goes to infinity.

Comment: So is the general rule just to multiply the function by H(t) minus the interval it's defined in? Regardless of whether it's less than, greater than, or less than or less than or equal to?

Comment: Now how do I take the laplace tranform of this?

Comment: If your interval is the function starting from 0 minus the function that starts from 2, the point 2 is not present and the point 0 it is.